# Method return default value

Tags: c#, interface, return-value, value-type, reference-type

Why am I allowed to return null within a method declaration, which could also return a value type?
I thought interfaces such as IList<T> have no restriction on the type of their implementation.
Further, how would one check if a method returning a IList<T> returned the default value?

```cs
public IList<int> SomeMethod()
{
    // Allowed
    return new MyStructList();

    // Allowed
    return null;
}

public struct MyStructList : IList<int>
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `SomeMethod` method returns an `IList<int>`. `IList<T>` is an interface, which is a reference type. `null` is an allowable value for a reference type.

When you do `return new MyStructList()`, that's essentially shorthand for:

```
IList<int> ret = new MyStructList();
return ret;
```

That `IList<int> ret = new MyStructList();` boxes `MyStructList()`: a box is allocated for it, the `MyStructList` is copied into the box, and a reference to the box is created and assigned to `ret`. This is necessary, as `ret` has type `IList<int>`, and `IList<T>` is a reference type, so `ret` can only contain references.

Comment: Are interfaces generally reference types?
Meaning, that if I have a struct that implements an Interface and I use the struct as that Interface im also boxing it before?

Comment: Good explanation of this can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/abhinaba/c-structs-and-interface

Comment: Interfaces are always reference types. Doing `IInterface x = new SomeValueType()` will always box the value type.